# What is a function called when every element in the codomain mapped with a unique element in the domain

Tags: functions

What is a function called when every element in the codomain is mapped with a unique element in the domain? (All elements in the domain are not necessarily mapped to an element in the codomain)

The closest I found is an onto function, but the unique condition is not necessarily true for onto functions.

Comment: Unless I’m misunderstanding, this is equivalent to being a bijection.

Comment: An ill-defined function. All elements in the domain of the function must be mapped by your function. And where else can they map to, if not the codomain, by definition?

Comment: If not every input has a corresponding output, it is called a _partial function_ (and is not considered to be a function, the same way a toy car is not a car and a dwarf planet is not a planet)

Comment: You probably want, then, partial functions that are bijective on their domains of definition (the portion of the domain where the partial function is defined)